# Window set to size around content leaves gap on each side

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, window

Can someone please tell me why, even though I've set my Window to SizeToContent and my content is Width=40 does the app load bigger across the Width?

The following example sizes to height, but the width is about 100 pixels (estimation).

Thanks

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.RetailButs"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="RetailButs" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStyle="None" MinWidth="0" >
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRooty" Width="40" Height="40">
            <Border x:Name="LayoutRootx" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="4" >
            </Border>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra size you have got comes from 3 top right window buttons.

So the best solution is just take buttons out **(1)** and put some minimum size for the window **(2)**.

Try this and it will be exactly what you need.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"  Width="40" Height="40" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRooty" Width="40" Height="40">

        <Border x:Name="LayoutRootx" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="4" >

        </Border>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question recently which i was unable to find. The size is that which would be needed if the `WindowStyle` were the default 3D border with all the buttons which take up a lot of space. I think there is some way to update the layout, maybe you can figure something out.

**Edit:** Set the window's `Width="0"` (or any other value for that matter) and it should update correctly. The size to content will override the value.

*(If you set the `WindowStyle` to `ToolWindow` it always fits correctly)*